# Unable to get elements/properties from within a class tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

Im quite a newbie to jquery so if this doesnt make sense much then let me try to explain.

I currently have a section whereby when I click the text, it will create a new row and populate a "default" button. The issue I am having is every time i click it, it populates with a blank element (see 'result im getting') rather then the button itself (see 'what i want it to be').

I have attached my code, would greatly appreciate any help.

```
var row = $("<DIV></DIV>").addClass("row resource").attr("resource", "new");
var label = $("<SPAN></SPAN>").addClass("label imaged").text("New resource");
label.append($("<SPAN>&nbsp</SPAN>").addClass("defaultJobType").attr("title", "defaultJobType"));
```

```html
<SPAN class="defaultJobType"><input id = "setDefaultJobType" type="submit" name="Default" value="Set Default"/>&nbsp</SPAN>
```

Result im getting

```
<span class="defaultJobType" title="defaultJobType">&nbsp;</span>
```

what I want it to be

```
<span class="defaultJobType"><input id="setDefaultJobType" type="submit" name="Default" value="Set Default">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: Can you please post all the relevant code. This is missing the click handler and where you are appending the HTML you create. Also you don't create an `input` element anywhere in your code - hence why it's not in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following,

```
var row = $("<DIV></DIV>").addClass("row resource").attr("resource", "new");

var label = $("<SPAN></SPAN>").addClass("label imaged").text("New resource");
var spanEl = $("<SPAN>&nbsp</SPAN>").addClass("defaultJobType");
spanEl.append($("<input id = 'setDefaultJobType' type='submit' name='Default' value='Set Default'/>"));        

label.append(spanEl);
```

Comment: Maybe i spoke to soon, however, the input id = setDefaultJobType actually doesnt trigger the actual setDefaultJobType function. Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to bind event on newly created elements. I am not sure what is your entire logic or code so can only suggest you. Also if you are creating elements through javascript then make sure you bind them to proper parent. Here input should be appended into form element.